# FileZilla crash when trying to SFTP transfer

Tags: high-sierra, homebrew, crash, ftp

I can still log on SFTP sites with my FileZilla 3.38.1 but as soon as I try to upload or download it crashes (window just disappears).
Plan FTP seems to download the file but FileZilla crashes after that regardless.

The one thing I did earlier today (Mac's been on for a couple of days) was to try to install a newer version of `nano` with Brew which might have messed with libraries, I still had the terminal open to copy the following output:

```
    ==> Updated Formulae
cmake ✔                    docker-compose-completion  fn                         hugo                       mesa                       pulumi                     rustup-init                xmake
akamai                     easyengine                 frugal                     juju                       mongodb@3.4                rancher-cli                sbt@0.13
amqp-cpp                   ethereum                   gmsh                       libextractor               mongodb@3.6                rebar3                     smimesign
docfx                      exploitdb                  golang-migrate             macvim                     mpc                        rke                        swiftformat
docker-compose             faas-cli                   helmfile                   mame                       node-build                 rom-tools                  vim

==> Installing dependencies for nano: ncurses
==> Installing nano dependency: ncurses
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ncurses-6.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/bc/bc5a61af5553ac748657e276ffcd604fca3d74db0b10855b9e4163ae45f7cb72?__gda__=exp=1543484157~hmac=42857b18481f59cfcfc9afe14de06cdb1f96a6451b302bb6912a5a9791c6985b&response-co
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring ncurses-6.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
ncurses is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have ncurses first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find ncurses you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ncurses/include"

For pkg-config to find ncurses you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1: 3,869 files, 8.3MB
==> Installing nano
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/nano-3.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/2f/2f5813de778b93cf4b5fe064ef4f4e5c93db76f3c1a6fd9c330341ba0519666d?__gda__=exp=1543484169~hmac=55a8199108572113a6783f7e2926d927c1aa0317391dfb8c4b0ad4dc5ef1fd32&response-co
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring nano-3.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/nano/3.2: 98 files, 2.4MB
==> Caveats
==> ncurses
ncurses is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have ncurses first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find ncurses you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ncurses/include"

For pkg-config to find ncurses you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I did a reboot in the hopes that any environment variables were only temporary but that did not help. Not very familiar with that side of macOS.
Tried using AppCleaner to delete FileZilla and "re-install" but it doesn't seem to have cleared everything as I still had my saved sites not sure how to do that properly.

Also I now see in the console 
a kernel Volatile ERROR
`"Sandbox: filezilla(1751) System Policy: deny(2) file-write-unlink /Users/<me>/Library/Saved Application State/org.filezilla-project.filezilla.savedState/restorecount.plist"`

On startup the `filezilla` process itself raises 3 log entries `UNIX error exception: 17` but not much else.

Comment: It creates the file locally (downloads) or remotely (uploads) but crashes after that. I think the Sandbox log entry is also the reason why I can't fully clean up with AppCleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a root cause but the only thing that did fix it was to delete the FileZilla configuration folde `~/.config/filezilla` and re-launch FileZilla.

You can export your saved sites and settings and restore them the above procedure.